# Are all SFP+ tranceivers usable for FEX between Nexus 5000 and Nexus 2000?

Tags: cisco, fabric, cisco-nexus

I am looking at building a network with Nexus 5000 parent switches and Nexus 2000 fabric extenders.

The mystery at the moment is what kind of SFP+ tranceivers are required for cross-connecting racks.

Right now I am considering FET-10G, but I am not sure that 100m is long enough given the separation between racks is potentially very large since it is a rented rack environment.

Are all SFP+ tranceivers usable for FEX between Nexus 5000 and Nexus 2000?

Specifically, can SFP-10G-SR transceivers be used for longer distance FEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use OM3 fibre you can get to 300m with those SR's, 400m with OM4 but that's spendy :)

Ideally you'll want the 2k's on 4.2(1)N2(1) or higher and the 5k's on at least 5.0(3)N1(1B).